# how to set route in boostrap tabs using with angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am including vertical tabs in angulrjs. I have successfully created tabs using bootstrap now had a problem while accessing tabs in angularjs. so kindly anyone help me to get to solve this problem.

here is my html part

```
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3"> <!-- required for floating -->
      <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left sideways">
        <li class="active "><a href="#home-v" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;">BIO&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#profile-v" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;"> FRIENDS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#messages-v" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#settings-v" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;">PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#vedios-v" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;">VEDIOS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#INVITES-v" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;">INVITES</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-lg-9"  >
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content" style="background-color:#EDEAEA;">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="home-v" style="height:100%;"><p style="margin-left:3.5%; margin-top:3.4%;">Football quarterback Dan Marino was born in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in 1961. A first round pick of the Miami Dolphins in the 1983 NFL draft, Marino led the franchise for 17 seasons. A durable QB with a big arm, he set numerous passing records, registering his finest season in 1984, when he threw for 5,084 yards and 48 touchdowns, both NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also league records. He retired.</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="profile-v" style="height:100%;">
        <p style="margin-left:3%;">
        Football quarterback Dan Marino was born in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in 1961. A first round pick of the Miami Dolphins in the 1983 NFL draft, Marino led the franchise for 17 seasons. A durable QB with a big arm, he set numerous passing records, registering his finest season in 1984, when he threw for 5,084 yards and 48 touchdowns, both NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also league records. He ret.</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="messages-v" style="height:100%;"><p style="margin-left:3.5%;">
        Football quarterback Dan Marino was born in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in 1961. A first round pick of the Miami Dolphins in the 1983 NFL draft, Marino led the franchise for 17 seasons. A durable QB with a big arm, he set numerous passing records, registering his finest season in 1984, when he threw for 5,084 yards and 48 touchdowns, both NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also le</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="settings-v" style="height:100%;"><p style="margin-left:3.5%;">
        Football quarterback Dan Marino was born in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in 1961. A first round pick of the Miami Dolphins in the 1983 NFL draft, Marino led the franchise for 17 seasons. A durable QB with a big arm, he set numerous passing records, registering his finest season in 1984, when he threw for 5,084 yards and 48 touchdowns, both NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also league records. He retired in 2000..13 yards and 408 touchdowns, also league records. .</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="#vedios-v"><p style="margin-left:3.5%;">
        Football quarterback Dan Marino was born in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in 1961. A first round pick of the Miami Dolphins in the 1983 NFL draft, Marino led the franchise for 17 seasons. A durable QB with a big arm, he set numerous passing records, registering his finest season in 1984, when he threw for 5,084 yards and 48 touchdowns, both NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also league records. He retired in 2000.. NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also leagu.</p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="INVITES-v"><p style="margin-left:3.5%;">
        Football quarterback Dan Marino was born in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, in 1961. A first round pick of the Miami Dolphins in the 1983 NFL draft, Marino led the franchise for 17 seasons. A durable QB with a big arm, he set numerous passing records, registering his finest season in 1984, when he threw for 5,084 yards and 48 touchdowns, both NFL records. Overall, he threw for 58,913 yards and 408 touchdowns, also league records. He retired .</p></div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

style sheet

```
        .tabs-left, .tabs-right {
        border-bottom: none;

        }
    .tabs-left {

       }
  .tabs-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #ddd !important;;
 }
  .tabs-left>li, .tabs-right>li {
  float: none;

      }

        .tabs-left>li.active>a,
        .tabs-left>li.active>a:hover,
     .tabs-left>li.active>a:focus {

       background: #EDEAEA !important;
      border-radius: 0.5ex !important;
       }

    .tabs-right>li.active>a,
       .tabs-right>li.active>a:hover,
      .tabs-right>li.active>a:focus {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
    .tabs-left>li>a {

      margin-right: 0 !important;;
     display:block  !important;;
     }
      .tabs-right>li>a {
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
       margin-right: 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your url which starts with #
And write ng-click on tabs and set that url and

```
$window.location = url;
```

Comment: i have implement this ... for next i wont be able to move particular tab.. how to move particular section using tab id... ?? i appricated